# WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chromedriver version : 2.33
Selenium tests still pick up the older chromedriver version. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: your post is not clear. Can you please post details with the question what you have tried and got the exception?

Comment: I got it working. I had changed in PATH environment variables the path to newer chromedriver version. But it was picking from some place else. I don't really understand why but i deleted all other instances present of chromedriver other than the recent one